Why is Sammy's family not talking to her in "Chaos Theory"?
In Jurassic World: Chaos Theory, Sammy shows some discontent because she feels herself growing distant from both Yasmina—due to their physical distance and Sammy's attitude toward her PTSD—and her family, who are not talking to her.
The most obvious reason for this would be because of her spying on Jurassic World for Mantah Corp, without their permission. However, since she did it to save their ranch, it seems hard to think that they would hold it against her—particularly since we see that she is actually running the ranch as of the first season of Chaos Theory, so they clearly trusted her enough to hand its management over to her. Another obvious possibility would be that they disliked her relationship with Yasmina; however, as of the end of Camp Cretaceous, they seemed extremely happy with it.
And overall, both these theories run into the problem that it is implied that they only stopped talking at some point after Brooklynn's apparent death, whereas both these things should have been obvious to her family long before.
Why is Sammy's family no longer talking to her (or vice versa)?
